# PHP Sorting String Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, case

I am trying to print the array in alphabetical order, and capitalize the first letters of each string. It says there is an invalid argument in the foreach().

```
<?php
$stringsArr = array("zulu", "alpha", "omega");
function sortAndTitle($arr){
    $newArr = ucfirst(sort($arr));
    foreach($newArr as $value){
        echo $value . "<br/>";
    };
};
sortAndTitle($stringsArr);
?>
```

Comment: I'm confused: why does your code do this with a function declaration and then a function call, where the array isn't even passed by reference? Why don't you just do this directly? `$mapped = array_map("ucfirst", sort($stringsArr)))` done.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans review what `sort()` returns. It modifies the array in-place and returns a `bool` so your code doesn't work either.

Comment: So just sort in place, then array_map like Jibin Matthew' answer.

Answer (score 3):

[sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) does not accept string, [ucfirst()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) does not accept array.  No need to store sort($arr) in a variable because it is sorted inside. It is natural to add flag type in the sorting as well. For
Try this:

```
<?php
$stringsArr = array("zulu", "alpha", "omega");

function sortAndTitle($arr){
    sort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);
    foreach($arr as $value){
        echo ucfirst($value). "<br/>";
    }
}
sortAndTitle($stringsArr);
?>
```

Note: All parameters in php functions are passed as values. If you want to modify your array (or any parameter passed into a function), remember to declare the function with the array parameter prefixed with the ampersand(&). So in your case sortAndTitle(&$stringsArr).

Comment: Thanks this seems to be the fastest fix to my code. I'll be looking into the parameters of sort() now.

Comment: @Nathan Wonz, If this answer is helpful, you can click the tick icon to accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(sort($stringsArr)){
   print_r(array_map('ucfirst', $stringsArr));
}else{
   echo "sort failed";
}
```

So for you case it would look like

```
<?php     
 function sortAndTitle($arr){
     if(sort($arr)){
        print_r(array_map('ucfirst', $arr));
     }else{
        echo "sort failed";
     }
 }
 $stringsArr = array("zulu", "alpha", "omega");
 sortAndTitle($stringsArr);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two errors.

The `sort()` function does not return an `array` but a simple `bool`.

The `ucfirst()` function does not accept an `array` but only a `string`.

Try this instead:

```
<?php

function sortAndTitle($arr) {
    sort($arr);
    return array_map('ucfirst', $arr);
}

print_r(sortAndTitle([ "alhpa", "beta", "gamma" ]);
```

It's no use to test the result of `sort()` if you know that `$arr` is an array. It will only fail if it is not an array, so don't bother with it too much. The final `?>` can (and should!) be omitted. It is a safer way of writing code for specific frameworks such as Symfony.

Also, don't print inside the `sortAndTtitle()` function. As the name says, just *sort* and *title* (capitalize).

The last line is just for your testing leisure.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your insights into the problem. I learned something from all of the responses. One thing I wasn't clear on was that I needed to permanently change the Array values to UpperCase First Letter. Here is the code I managed to do that with. If there is a faster way please comment.

```
$stringsArr = array("zulu", "alpha", "omega");
function sortAndTitle($arr){
    sort($arr);
    for($x = 0; $x < count($arr); $x++){
        $arr[$x] = ucfirst($arr[$x]);
    };
    return implode(", ", $arr);
};
echo sortAndTitle($stringsArr);
```